# My VBA code doesn't run every second time I run it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem with my VBA code. On the first try it runs perfectly. On the second time I get the error message: "The remote-server-computer does not exist or is not available". If I run the code again afterwards, it works. But every second time I run it, it doesn't work. Why does this occur?

```
Sub to_word()
    
    Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
        WrdApp.Visible = True
        WrdApp.Activate
        
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Add
    a = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 6 To a
    
        If i = 9 Then
            WrdApp.Selection.Font.Bold = True
            WrdApp.Selection.Font.Underline = True
            ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=("Text" & vbNewLine)
        End If
        
        If Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 5).Value = "Ja" Then
            
            Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 4).Copy
            WrdDoc.Characters.Last.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I check: is it more reliable if you change `ActiveDocument` to `WrdDoc`?

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: Note that `WrdDoc.Characters.Last.PasteSpecial` is the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pastespecial) of Word **not Excel!** and therefore `xlPasteValues` does not make any sense as the first parameter is `IconIndex` and setting that `xlPasteValues` cannot work.

Comment: @Robson changing it to `WrdDoc` was the solution. Thanks

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I use the code to export data to a word document

Comment: @Mazze Still this code `WrdDoc.Characters.Last.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is wrong and does not make any sense at all. Remove the `xlPasteValues`. Read the documentation in the link I gave and you will see this method is different from the Excel method!

Comment: Each time you run the code you create a new instance of Word. You should include `WrdApp.Quit` at the end of the routine. Also you can avoid using the clipboard by using `WrdDoc.Characters.Last.Text = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, 4).Value`.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I better avoid the copy and past method and go with your approach.
Does anyone know why the code works fine on windows but on Mac I get a run-time error?

Comment: There has been an issue with cross-application code in Office for Mac for several years. No one seems to know the exact cause but it may be due to Office running sandboxed on macOS